# change input box into hyperlink

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this code that is from a Google Map Marker thing. I im around this a couple of days.
Now i have this code in map_process.php

```
$mName      = filter_var($_POST["name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$mAddress   = filter_var($_POST["address"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$mType      = filter_var($_POST["type"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);


$results = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO markers (name, address, lat, lng, type) VALUES ('$mName','$mAddress',$mLat, $mLng, '$mType')");
if (!$results) {  
      header('HTTP/1.1 500 Error: Could not create marker!'); 
      exit();

}

$output = '<h1 class="marker-heading">'.$mName.'</h1><p>'.$mAddress.'</p><p>'.$mType.'</p>';
exit($output);
```

}

and i want to change the text inserted in the input box into a clickable link. Can you help me?

i was trying something like this

```
    <html> 
<head> 
<title>Links</title> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function CreateLink() { 
  var str = ''; 
  str += '<a href="http://'+document.getElementById('TBox').value+'">'+document.getElementById('TBox').value+'</a>'; 
  var txt = "<p>";  
  var tmp = 'http://'+document.getElementById('TBox').value; 
  str += txt.link(tmp); 
  document.getElementById('tlink').innerHTML = str; 
} 
</script> 
</head> 
<body> 
<input type="text" id="TBox" value="" size="40"> 
<button onclick="CreateLink()">Create Link</button> 

<br> 
<div id="tlink"></div> 

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: What is the problem? Does the Google Maps code have anything to do with the problem? Your HTML is working on its own, and creates a link based on the text in the text input field.

Comment: yes, but what i want is that when the people insert the data in box name, adress, website, the return is name, adress and a clickable link..

Answer (score 0):

`.link` method wraps your text around an anchor tag with href specified in the argument. Here's a more succinct implementation:

```
function CreateLink() {
    var txt = document.getElementById('TBox').value;
    var href = 'http://' + txt;
    var str = txt.link(href);

    document.getElementById('tlink').innerHTML = str;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D98c6/2/)

Comment: and where i isert that? i was trying and changing variables but it doesnt work